# Too many coefficients in regression

Tags: r, linear-regression

I have a data frame with about 800 points in it. The table looks roughly like this:

| V4 | V92 |
| --- | --- |
| .5 | .02 |
| .25 | .12 |
| .5 | 1.02 |
| .45 | -.02 |
| .5 | .32 |
| 1.5 | .42 |

This goes on for about 850 rows.

I ran a linear regression for this using the code:

```r
lmMRE <- lm(data.frame$V92~data.frame$V4)
```

For some reason, when I run this code, my regression has 157 coefficients.

Why might this be? How do I change this so I only have 1?

Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like your values are characters/factors rather than numeric columns. We can't really tell based on what you have provided. Make sure to share data in [reproducible format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) like `dput()`. You can also try `lm(data.frame$V92~as.numeric(as.character(data.frame$V4)))` but it would be better to properly import your data in the first place.

Comment: Try [to convert factor to numeric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418128/how-to-convert-a-factor-to-integer-numeric-without-loss-of-information).

Answer (score 0):

There is clearly something wrong with your input data. Simulating your data gives the expected one coefficient. Check that both your dependent and independent data are numeric.

See code below.

```
library(tidyverse)

#create fake data
my_data <- data.frame("V4" = 1:800 + rnorm(800, 0, 2),
                      "V92" = seq(from = 1, to = 100, length.out = 800) ) 

#run regression
lmMRE <- lm(my_data$V92~my_data$V4)

#one coefficient
lmMRE

my_data %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = V4, y = V92)) +
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth(method=lm) +
  labs(title = "Sample regression",
       subtitle = paste0("Number of coefficients: ",
                         length(lmMRE$coefficients) - 1))
```

[Sample Regression](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1h2Q.png)